# What is this futuristic typeface in the mAlert logo?

Tags: font-identification

Tried FontSquirrel, MyFonts, FontSpring, no exact match.

The "e" is particular.

Toxigenesis Regular is closest so far, but the A and e are different.

[image: mAlert logo]

Comment: Not sure on the font, but that knock off "Aladdin" genie is definitely standing in front of the cease and desist letter from Disney when they see it! ;)

Comment: Haha, I know. This is something I would talk to the client about but some clients are of a different kind and you just can't talk sense. They want precisely what they have been using, which was probably created by some ignorant designer.

Comment: I understand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name of the font is : SolPro Bold
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Do you mind telling me any tools that you used?